# program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When I run this following code it gives above error

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


   self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.firstViewController=[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *localNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.navigationController=localNavigationController;
    [localNavigationController release];
    UINavigationController *localFistNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.firstViewController];
    self.firstNavigationController=localFistNavigationController;
    [localNavigationController release];
   NSArray *twoBars=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.navigationController,self.firstNavigationController, nil];
    UITabBarController *localTAbBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [localTAbBarController setViewControllers:twoBars];
    self.tabBarController=localTAbBarController;
    [localTAbBarController release];
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

        return YES;
}
```

if i run following code it runs well

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
         [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                 initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.firstNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.firstViewController];
    NSArray *twoBars=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.navigationController,self.firstNavigationController, nil];

    self.tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:twoBars];

       [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];



    return YES;
```

i not understood what is the difference between these. in first one i just created local variables & assigned those to properties. in later one directly used the properties.
why it is giving the error- program recieved signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: make nslog in your viewDidLoad of ViewController and then check that are you able to access this view

Comment: To make EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes easier to debug go into Breakpoint Navigator and add an Exception Breakpoint (with default settings). 
Also in Scheme Editor check "Enable Zombie Objects" and "Log Exceptions" boxes. This will help you see where crash happened.

Comment: Use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). There's no reason not to.

Comment: please check all answer.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer. because of releasing same objects more than one time, it happens.
i have released `[localNavigationController release];` two times. later it must be

```
[localFirstNavigationController release];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in first one you releases some code and then after release you again that object like:

`[localTAbBarController release];` this. So may be thats why you got error- program recieved

signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". in second one you nicely use your object no releases so its work

fine.

Comment: no,even i directly assigns tabBarController property & not used any release mechanism on tabBarController it giving same error

Comment: i made following changes & tried but same error self.tabBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:twoBars];

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

hey i  use your code, here you get BAD_ACCESS on this bellow line see..

```
[localNavigationController release];
```

just comment it and you have not BAD_ACCESS

Comment: can you please explain what the reason behind this?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 hey here localNavigationController is allocate one time after it here Ravindra relese it and after two lines he also relese this object again which not alloc or not in class with reference so here it crash with second time release localNavigationController..

Answer (score 0):

Just check this line.

```
self.firstNavigationController=localFistNavigationController;
  -->>  [localNavigationController release];
```

It should be `[localFistNavigationController release];`